# Chrome vs rest of the browsers css issue

Tags: css, cross-browser

Live link here
http://soloveich.com/pr1-1/

There are three image links closer to content part of the page. 
Where does bottom part of the image go in Chrome, when hover?
Been looking at it for a while, and still can't figure out.

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="ml" href="#"><div class="tabs1"><div id="t1">
    </div></div>
    </a></li>        
    <li class="tabs2"><a class="ml" href="#"><div class="tabs1"> <div id="t2">
    </div></div>
    </a></li>
    <li class="tabs2"><a class="ml" href="#"><div class="tabs1"><div id="t3">
    </div></div>
   </a></li>  
</ul>
```

and the css

```
#tabs {
margin-top: 400px;
position: absolute;
}
#tabs ul li {
display: inline;
float: left;
}
.tabs1 {
height:200px;
width: 353px;
background-color: #fff;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: #D4360C;
border-top-width: 4px;
}

.tabs2 {
margin-left: 40px;
}

#t1 {
height: 256px;
width: 353px;
background-image: url(images/t1.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#t1:hover {
background-image: url(images/t1r.png);
}

#t2 {
height: 256px;
width: 353px;
background-image: url(images/t2.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#t2:hover {
background-image: url(images/t2r.png);
}

#t3 {
height: 256px;
width: 353px;
background-image: url(images/t3.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#t3:hover {
background-image: url(images/t3r.png);
}
```

Comment: What are you referring to? It seems to look the same to me across browsers and there isn't any image going missing.

Comment: Hm... Weird... Here is an image of what i'm talking about. http://soloveich.com/pr1-1/wp-content/themes/blankslate/1.jpg  chrome hover on top, and FF on the bottom. Is that just my computer lagging?

Comment: Strange. I only get a small flash as the hover image loads but then it looks normal. I'm on Chrome v31

Comment: Try using a sprite instead of loading a new image on hover.

Comment: does it turn red though?

Comment: Yes. You put all of the images together into the same image then position them how you like using 'background-position' in css. Check out this article which explains everything quite well: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/